Azure Devops Deployment pool target Registration script failed
The registration script failed to start the agent service. The server gets into the deployment pool in the azure devops, but the script reports error at the end.
This can be found in the _diag folder:
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO WindowsServiceControlManager] Verifying if the account has LogonAsService permission
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z ERR  NativeWindowsServiceHelper] Can't enumerate account rights, return code 3221225524.
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO NativeWindowsServiceHelper] Successfully grant logon as service privilage to account 'SYSTEM'
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO WindowsServiceControlManager] Create local group and grant folder permission to service logon account.
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Bin': 'C:\azagent\A2\bin'
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Root': 'C:\azagent\A2'
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO ConfigurationStore] Read setting file: 269 chars
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Bin': 'C:\azagent\A2\bin'
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Root': 'C:\azagent\A2'
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Work': 'C:\azagent\A2\_work'
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Bin': 'C:\azagent\A2\bin'
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO NativeWindowsServiceHelper] Calculated unique group name VSTS_AgentService_Gc0f76
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO NativeWindowsServiceHelper] Trying to create group VSTS_AgentService_Gc0f76
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO NativeWindowsServiceHelper] Local Group 'VSTS_AgentService_Gc0f76' created
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO NativeWindowsServiceHelper] Trying to add userName NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM to the group VSTS_AgentService_Gc0f76
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO NativeWindowsServiceHelper] Account 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' is added to local group 'VSTS_AgentService_Gc0f76'.
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO NativeWindowsServiceHelper] Set full access control to group for the folder C:\azagent\A2
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO NativeWindowsServiceHelper] Set full access control to group for the folder C:\azagent\A2\_work
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO NativeWindowsServiceHelper] Local group 'VSTS_AgentService_Gc0f76' already has full control to path 'C:\azagent\A2\_work'.
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO Terminal] WRITE LINE: Granting file permissions to 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z WARN NativeWindowsServiceHelper] NetIsServiceAccount return code is 3221225695
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO NativeWindowsServiceHelper] Account 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' is managed service account: False.
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Bin': 'C:\azagent\A2\bin'
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Starting process:
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   File name: '"C:\azagent\A2\bin\AgentService.exe"'
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Arguments: 'init'
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Working directory: ''
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Require exit code zero: 'True'
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Encoding web name:  ; code page: ''
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Force kill process on cancellation: 'False'
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Redirected STDIN: 'False'
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Persist current code page: 'False'
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Keep redirected STDIN open: 'False'
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   High priority process: 'False'
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   ContinueAfterCancelProcessTreeKillAttempt: 'False'
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Sigint timeout: '00:00:07.5000000'
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Sigterm timeout: '00:00:02.5000000'
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper]   Try to use graceful shutdown: False
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] OOM score adjustment is Linux-only.
[2024-06-20 10:58:33Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Process started with process id 9564, waiting for process exit.
[2024-06-20 10:58:36Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
[2024-06-20 10:58:36Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] STDOUT/STDERR stream read finished.
[2024-06-20 10:58:36Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Exited process 9564 with exit code -1073741819
[2024-06-20 10:58:36Z INFO ProcessInvokerWrapper] Finished process 9564 with exit code -1073741819, and elapsed time 00:00:02.5608747.
[2024-06-20 10:58:36Z ERR  Agent] Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Util.ProcessExitCodeException: Exit code -1073741819 returned from process: file name '"C:\azagent\A2\bin\AgentService.exe"', arguments 'init'.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Util.ProcessInvoker.ExecuteAsync(String workingDirectory, String fileName, String arguments, IDictionary`2 environment, Boolean requireExitCodeZero, Encoding outputEncoding, Boolean killProcessOnCancel, InputQueue`1 redirectStandardIn, Boolean inheritConsoleHandler, Boolean keepStandardInOpen, Boolean highPriorityProcess, Boolean continueAfterCancelProcessTreeKillAttempt, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Agent.Sdk\ProcessInvoker.cs:line 389
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.ProcessInvokerWrapper.ExecuteAsync(String workingDirectory, String fileName, String arguments, IDictionary`2 environment, Boolean requireExitCodeZero, Encoding outputEncoding, Boolean killProcessOnCancel, InputQueue`1 redirectStandardIn, Boolean inheritConsoleHandler, Boolean keepStandardInOpen, Boolean highPriorityProcess, Boolean continueAfterCancelProcessTreeKillAttempt, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent\ProcessInvoker.cs:line 329
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Configuration.NativeWindowsServiceHelper.InstallService(String serviceName, String serviceDisplayName, String logonAccount, String logonPassword, Boolean setServiceSidTypeAsUnrestricted) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Agent.Listener\Configuration.Windows\NativeWindowsServiceHelper.cs:line 500
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Configuration.WindowsServiceControlManager.ConfigureService(AgentSettings settings, CommandSettings command) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Agent.Listener\Configuration.Windows\WindowsServiceControlManager.cs:line 142
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConfigureAsync(CommandSettings command) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Agent.Listener\Configuration\ConfigurationManager.cs:line 442
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Agent.ExecuteCommand(CommandSettings command) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Agent.Listener\Agent.cs:line 103
[2024-06-20 10:58:36Z ERR  Terminal] WRITE ERROR: Exit code -1073741819 returned from process: file name '"C:\azagent\A2\bin\AgentService.exe"', arguments 'init'.


Here is the  registration script downloaded from azure devops:
$ErrorActionPreference="Stop";If(-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent() ).IsInRole( [Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")){ throw "Run command in an administrator PowerShell prompt"};If($PSVersionTable.PSVersion -lt (New-Object System.Version("3.0"))){ throw "The minimum version of Windows PowerShell that is required by the script (3.0) does not match the currently running version of Windows PowerShell." };If(-NOT (Test-Path $env:SystemDrive\'azagent')){mkdir $env:SystemDrive\'azagent'}; cd $env:SystemDrive\'azagent'; for($i=1; $i -lt 100; $i++){$destFolder="A"+$i.ToString();if(-NOT (Test-Path ($destFolder))){mkdir $destFolder;cd $destFolder;break;}}; $agentZip="$PWD\agent.zip";$DefaultProxy=[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy;$securityProtocol=@();$securityProtocol+=[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol;$securityProtocol+=[Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol=$securityProtocol;$WebClient=New-Object Net.WebClient; $Uri='https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/3.240.1/vsts-agent-win-x64-3.240.1.zip';if($DefaultProxy -and (-not $DefaultProxy.IsBypassed($Uri))){$WebClient.Proxy= New-Object Net.WebProxy($DefaultProxy.GetProxy($Uri).OriginalString, $True);}; $WebClient.DownloadFile($Uri, $agentZip);Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem;[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory( $agentZip, "$PWD");.\config.cmd --deploymentgroup --deploymentgroupname "xxxxxxx prod" --agent $env:COMPUTERNAME --runasservice --work '_work' --url 'https://xxxxxxx.visualstudio.com/' --projectname 'xxxxxx'; Remove-Item $agentZip;

This happens if I run manually the config.cmd file:
PS C:\azagent\A2> .\config.cmd --deploymentgroup

  ___                      ______ _            _ _
 / _ \                     | ___ (_)          | (_)
/ /_\ \_____   _ _ __ ___  | |_/ /_ _ __   ___| |_ _ __   ___  ___
|  _  |_  / | | | '__/ _ \ |  __/| | '_ \ / _ \ | | '_ \ / _ \/ __|
| | | |/ /| |_| | | |  __/ | |   | | |_) |  __/ | | | | |  __/\__ \
\_| |_/___|\__,_|_|  \___| \_|   |_| .__/ \___|_|_|_| |_|\___||___/
                                   | |
        agent v3.240.1             |_|          (commit 6b1fcb5)


>> Connect:

Enter server URL > https://xxxxx.visualstudio.com/
Enter authentication type (press enter for PAT) >
Enter personal access token > ****************************************************
Connecting to server ...

>> Register Agent:

Enter Project name > xxxx
Enter Deployment Group name > xxxx prod
Enter agent name (press enter for xxxxAPP1xxxx) >
Scanning for tool capabilities.
Connecting to the server.
Enter deployment group tags for agent? (Y/N) (press enter for N) >
Successfully added the agent
Testing agent connection.
Enter work folder (press enter for _work) >
2024-06-21 12:33:05Z: Settings Saved.
Enter run agent as service? (Y/N) (press enter for N) > Y
Enter enable SERVICE_SID_TYPE_UNRESTRICTED for agent service (Y/N) (press enter for N) >
Enter User account to use for the service (press enter for NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM) >
Granting file permissions to 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.
Error reported in diagnostic logs. Please examine the log for more details.
    - C:\azagent\A2\_diag\Agent_20240621-123033-utc.log
Exit code -1073741819 returned from process: file name '"C:\azagent\A2\bin\AgentService.exe"', arguments 'init'.
PS C:\azagent\A2>

What can cause this kind of error?
I searched for this error message, but i've not found relevant solutions.

Can you provide the detailed command you were running to install the deployment target? And when you run the command, do you open the command prompt as administrator?

I've inserted the registration script into the question. I've ran the script in administrator powershell prompt.

Does the machine have any firewall or proxy server set? If so, you might need to follow this docs to add the Outbound connections related IP addresses and domain URLs into the whitelist.  @FerencGajdos

After you download and unzip the installation package, you can try to only run the command .\config.cmd --deploymentgroup, and then manually enter/select the required parameters according to the prompts step by step. This can help to narrow down which step causes the issue. @FerencGajdos

I've included the output of config.cmd. I think it is not a firewall issue, because the registration is succesfull in azure devops.  @BrightRan-MSFT

At the step "Enter User account to use for the service (press enter for NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM)", try to use the username and password that you logon the Windows machine, instead of using the default Windows built-in account 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. As the default Windows built-in account might not have the permissions to access some directories/files and start some processes on the machine. @FerencGajdos

I tried that. I used admin account but it still doesn't run. I tried run the config without service registration and the script worked without error. After that I've managed to start with run.cmd. This way I've deployed succesfully, but this way the agent need to be started manually. @BrightRan-MSFT

You might need to check if there is any policies applied to your machine that will restrict the agent service to be registered and started. @FerencGajdos

In addition, check if you can register and start other services on the machine? If also cannot, as mentioned above, you need to check whether there are nay restrictions applied to the machine. @FerencGajdos

Ok. Thank you for your help. I've managed to start and install several services on the server. At the moment it is enough for me to start the agent manually.  @BrightRan-MSFT

Do you mean that you can configure the deployment agent to run in interactive mode instead of service mode? @FerencGajdos

Yes, I can run it with run.cmd, and it works fine. I can do deployment, but I can't configure the agent as a service. @BrightRan-MSFT

So, as mentioned previously, you might need to check whether there are any restrictions applied to the machine that does not allow you to run the agent in service mode, if you want to configure the agent to run as service.  Anyway, if configuring the agent to run in interactive mode also is ok for you, you can just do it. @FerencGajdos

As we have discussed in above comments, there might be some restrictions applied to the machine that does not allow you to run the agent in service mode.
As the workaround, you can configure the agent to run in interactive mode. To use the agent to run pipeline jobs, you need to manually sign in the machine and then execute the script '.\run.cmd' in the installation directory of the agent to start the agent.
You also can configure the agent to run in interactive mode with auto-logon enabled (runAsAutoLogon). By this way, every time when you manually sign in the machine, it will automatically open the command prompt to start the agent, and you do not need to go to the the installation directory of the agent to manually start the agent.

